# Prestashop 1.6 how to send shop logo in emails?

Tags: prestashop

In older version of prestashop (1.4) I would use `<img src="{shop_logo}">`

but in current version (1.6.1.4) when I use this syntax it automatically turn it to `<img src="http://t.clicktoamerica.com/admin1/{shop_logo}">` 
(ie it adds the shop domain and admin path)

and the logo is not displayed.

What is the correct syntax to add a logo in emails ?

EDIT

The syntax `<img src="{shop_logo}">` is correct however because of a bug the domain is added when editing with the TinyMce editor, therefore a simple by-pass is to edit the emails html files directly (with external editor)

The question remain - how to solve this bug?

Answer (score 0):

In `js/admin/tinymce.inc.js`

find the line: `relative_urls:false` and change it to `relative_urls:true`